# "Property 'rates' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor"

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to make as many possible projects as possible to get into the work flow. In this project I'm trying to do a currency converter but it seems to be wrong with rates. Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Its the rates in `OnInit` - it complains about.

This is my main component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {CurrencyExchangeService} from '../services/exchange-rates.service';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-valutaomraknare',
  templateUrl: './valutaomraknare.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./valutaomraknare.component.scss']
})
export class ValutaomraknareComponent implements OnInit {

  amount = 1;
  from = 'CAD';
  to = 'USD';
  rates: {[key: string]: number};

  convert(): number{
    return this.amount * this.rates[this.to];
  }

  loadRates(){
    this.service.getRates(this.from).subscribe(res => this.rates = res.rates);
  }

  getAllCurrencies(): string[]{
    return Object.keys(this.rates);
  }

  constructor(private service: CurrencyExchangeService) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loadRates();
  }

}
```

exchange rates service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ExchangeRatesResponse } from './interface/exchange-rates-response';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CurrencyExchangeService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {  }

  getRates(base: string): Observable<ExchangeRatesResponse> {
    return this.http.get<ExchangeRatesResponse>(`https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?base=${base}`);
  }
}
```

exchange rates response

```
export interface ExchangeRatesResponse {
    rates: {
        [key: string]: number
    },
    base: string,
    date: string
}
```

Comment: Initialize `rates` with empty object: `rates: {[key: string]: number} = {};`

Answer (score 1):

`rates: {[key: string]: number};` declares the `rates` property and gives it a type, but doesn't give it an initial value. Your class's constructor also doesn't assign anything to `rates`, and the type doesn't allow `undefined` (the default value for a property), hence the error that it's never initialized to anything.

Given the type you've assigned to it, you can initialize it with a blank object;

```typescript
rates: {[key: string]: number} = {};
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^
```

Comment: It has a construcotr, but it does not assign a value to rates there

Comment: @Lesiak - Doh! Thanks. I didn't scroll down far enough!

Comment: Also worth adding that in older Angular projects, if you have strict null checks disabled, the code presented in OP will work.

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much!! :D Angular got fun agian ;)